# Why do two windows appear when I connect styles?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, styles, ttk

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jagOc.jpg)I have a code like this:

```
from tkinter import Tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

"""Styles"""
style = ttk.Style()
style.configure('OrangeButton.TButton', foreground='white', background='#ff9203')
style.map('OrangeButton.TButton',
          foreground=[('pressed', 'white'), ('active', 'white')],
          background=[('pressed', '!disabled', '#adadad'), ('active', '#de8e26')])

root = Tk()

button = ttk.Button(root, text="Ok", width=20, style='OrangeButton.TButton')
button.pack(padx=50, pady=50)

root.mainloop()
```

I'm new at this. I searched the Internet for a solution, but could not find it. Everywhere they write about widthdraw(), but this does not help. Two windows always appear and the customized style is not applied to the button. What am I doing wrong? How do I search Google for this problem? Tell me please. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to define `ttk.Style()` inside the `root` window.

```py
from tkinter import Tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

root = Tk()

"""Styles"""
style = ttk.Style()

# add the these_use option and use the 'clam' theme
style.theme_use('clam')

style.configure('OrangeButton.TButton', foreground='white', background='#ff9203')
style.map('OrangeButton.TButton',
          foreground=[('pressed', 'white'), ('active', 'white')],
          background=[('pressed', '!disabled', '#adadad'), ('active', '#de8e26')])

button = ttk.Button(root, text="Ok", width=20, style='OrangeButton.TButton')
button.pack(padx=50, pady=50)

root.mainloop()
```

Hope this solves the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This helped to remove the second window. But for some reason, Style doesn’t work exactly. I read the ttk documentation and did the same, but it doesn't work. I indicate that the button is orange, but it is gray. How to fix it? Sorry for the stupid question.

Comment: Hey @rdbrg, I would suggest you to use `tk Buttons`. It is easier to customize compared to the `ttk` ones.

Comment: Since my solution solved your problem of ***Why do two windows appear when I connect styles?*** please accept the answer as it will help the community to recognize the correct solution. Cheers!

Comment: Hey @rdbrg, i updated the code add `style.theme_use('clam')` to make the button `orange`

Comment: of course. but I'm learning ttk. your advice "Tk Button will be easier" is understandable, but does not contribute to my learning. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: There are a set of predefined `themes` that you can use in the GUI to change the look of the widgets. I used the `clam` theme. Now your button will have a `orange` background. Cheers!